# How to use sort:create-index() in xquery

Tags: xml, sorting, xquery, paging

I have some xml documents:

```
<TEI xmlns="....." xmlns:nlp="....." xml:lang="cs" n="2AD0ABE0-D4D8-AS6C-8E27-63DPO5DFDA22">
<teiHeader>
    <fileDesc n="{2AD0ABE0-D4D8-AS6C-8E27-63DPO5DFDA22}">
        <titleStmt>
            <title>
             ........
```

There is a unique id (n) and I want use [sort:create-index()](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/sort&location=java%3aorg.exist.xquery.modules.sort.SortModule) for paging and sorting (sorte by n), but I don´t know what the third parameter is `($values as xs:anyAtomicType*)`. I gave my ids (n) there, However I get the error `$nodes and $values sequences need to have the some length.`

This is part of my code:
(This is my colection)

```
let $allSegments:= collection($collections)//tei:TEI//(tei:p | tei:l | tei:title | tei:item | tei:head)[tei:w[text:matches-regex(@nlp:lemma, '(p)(.*)', 'x')]]
```

(Here is my id colection)

```
for $segment in $allSegments
let $id := $segment/ancestor::tei:TEI/@n
```

(and here is paging)

```
let $segments := sort:create-index("index", $allSegments,  , <options order='ascending' empty='least'/>)
```

Thank's and sorry for my english.